# Softlayer Relationship Datacenter Pod NetwokZone Vlan and Subnets

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I have the following understanding of the softlayer infrastructure.

1. Softlayer Account has many Datacenters
2. Datacenters has many Pods
3. Pods has many Network Zones
4. Network Zones has many Vlans
5. Subnets belongs to the Vlans
   Is it correct ?

Via a softlayer API how can I fetch data to establish a relationship between above entities ( Account , Datacenter, POD , Network Zone, Vlans , Subnets )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resources have a different relationship, the datacenter cannot show the resources information that is hosted in it, they can only show information about it, the resources can show the information of where it is hosted.
the relationship that follows is the following:

> Account -> vlan -> primaryRouter -> datacenter
>
> Account -> vlan -> subnet -> podName

to obtain this information you can follow the following request:

```
https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Account/getNetworkVlans?objectMask=mask[primaryRouter[datacenterName],extensionRouter[datacenterName],secondaryRouter[datacenterName],primarySubnet[podName,reverseDomain]]
```

more reference:

https://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getNetworkVlans/

https://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Network_Vlan/

Comment: The network zone is domain DNS this has a direct relationship with the account, to obtain the information about the DNS, you can follow this request:
https://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getDomains/